# Where does "position:relative;" base it's offset?

Tags: html, css

From my layout, I noticed that my "navsprite" element does not center vertically when I use "position:relative;" as it's property, here is my document and it's basically an image sprite that I'm trying to center horizontally and vertically except as I said, it doesn't-vertically-if I use "position:relative;" instead of "position:absolute;" for my "navsprite" element.

```css
#navsprite {
  width: 134px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -67px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}
#navsprite li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
#navsprite a {
  height: 44px;
  display: block;
}
#home {
  left: 0px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(/favicon.ico) 0 0;
}
#prev {
  left: 63px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(/favicon.ico) -47px 0;
}
#next {
  left: 129px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(/favicon.ico) -91px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navsprite">
  <li id="home">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="prev">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="next">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now it has occurred to me that unlike "position:absolute;" which bases its offset from it's parent-body-element, "position:relative;" is totally not doing the same thing and I wonder where it is basing it's offset from since as you see, the image sprite only moves -22px to the top because for some reason, "top:50%;" doesn't have any effect at all(this is if it's position:relative;), or if does have any effect, then I don't know what and where.

So my question is, does "position:relative;" base its offset somewhere else? or does it not base its offset at all? or does it have any effect at all? or am I missing some sort of sub-rule for the property? What is happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: if it's relative can't you just use `text-align: center;` or `margin: auto;`?

Comment: I have no problem for the horizontal, it's the vertical part that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You could use margin with [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to do this.

Comment: Fair enough - this doesn't answer your actual question, but [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ntxuc8xg/1/) shows using `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` can vertically centre a div.

Comment: It works, but do I need to explicitly state the width/height for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:relative;` gets it's relative position from the nearest positioned parent.

So the trick is to do the following

```
<div id="#parent" style="position:relative;">
    <ul id="navsprite">
        <li id="home"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="prev"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="next"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basically the `position:relative;` on `#parent` does nothing, but tells the `#navsprite` where to relatively position from.

**Update:**

You need to have a height explicitly set somewhere that the `position:relative;` can relate to. You are telling it to be at `50%` from the top... but the question is 50% of what? You have to give it a hard value at some point or it will just use nothing and will appear not to work. Run my snippet to see.

```css
#navsprite {
  width: 134px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -67px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}
#navsprite li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
#navsprite a {
  height: 44px;
  display: block;
}
#home {
  left: 0px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(/favicon.ico) 0 0;
}
#prev {
  left: 63px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(/favicon.ico) -47px 0;
}
#next {
  left: 129px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(/favicon.ico) -91px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="position:relative; height:500px;">
  <ul id="navsprite">
    <li id="home">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="prev">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="next">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient What is the height of the parent element to your `#navsprite`?

Comment: I want it to be 100%/

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient 100% of what? See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say 100% of the visible browser view because I want it to be dynamic based on the available browser width and height, that's why I said 100%.

On the other hand, your solution works, thanks.

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient -To see where the issue is we would need to see everything up the tree to see where the height is being limited.- No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN articel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Notes),

> For relatively positioned elements, the `top` or `bottom` property
>   specifies the vertical offset from the normal position and the `left` or
>   `right` property specifies the horizontal offset.

From [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position),

> **relative**: The box's position is calculated according to the normal flow (this is called the position in normal flow). Then the box is
>   offset relative to its normal position.

Comment: I see, but why doesn't it offset from the top by 50% if that is true?

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient That's because CSS 2 didn't allow that. And even though it was [fixed](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/changes.html#q54) in CSS 2.1, most browsers didn't implement it. See [2992](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2992) and [260348](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=260348) Firefox bugs.

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient There are lots of questions about that in SO. For example, you can use `html, body{ height: 100%; }`

Comment: Wow it actually works, thank you so much, this is the solution that I've been looking for, I hope they fix this bug though.